# How to know when the KendoMobile ListView scrolls?

Tags: javascript, jquery, listview, telerik, kendo-mobile

I'm using a KendoMobile ListView. Is there a way to know when it is scrolled?

Scenario: I have a listview with titles of reports. I need to put a preview or detail panel which displays the details of the top item or the item that just scroll of the top of the list view. This detail panel shows Author, Date Published, Report Description, etc. I want to be able to scroll the report titles and as they hit the top of the list view I want to see the details for that item.

Any suggestions on how to accomplish this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use the scroll event of the Scroller - http://docs.telerik.com/kendo-ui/api/mobile/scroller#events-scroll. You can get the current visible Scroller by using the application scroller method - http://docs.telerik.com/kendo-ui/api/mobile/application#methods-scroller.

Comment: Ya I looked at that. I could add my list items in the html content but how would I know which items was selected on the scroll event?

Comment: Nothing gets selected on scroll :) Only thing you can do is to manually check the offsetTop of the item and if the scroll position is near it.